# case when query causing problems when executing a BQ query with bq command

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to execute a query via bash with `bq` command.  The query works when executed via web UI as well as via app script @ script.google.com.  However, when executed as a simple bash (or just via the cmd prompt) I keep receiving a `"Syntax error: Unexpected keyword THEN at [1:393]"`.  Col 393 refers to the middle part of a case when statement.  I've done lots of searching and can't figure out what I am doing wrong (since the query works elsewhere).  Might anyone have advice on what is causing the error?

```
bq query --destination_table abcdefcloud:ds_tables.daily_over_frequency_output
    --replace --use_legacy_sql=false 'with freq as
    (select month as month,campaign_id,campaign,case when  freq = '1' then 'a'
     when freq = '2' then 'b'
     when freq = '3-6' then 'c'
     when freq = '7-9' then 'd'
     when freq = '10-19' then 'e'
     when freq = '20-29' then 'f'
     when freq = '30-39' then 'g'
     when freq = '40-49' then 'h'
     when freq = '50-59' then 'i'
     when freq = '60-69' then 'j'
     when freq = '70-79' then 'k'
     when freq = '80-89' then 'l'
     when freq = '90-99' then 'm'
     when freq = '100+' then 'n'
     else 'other' end as sort,
     freq,sum(imps) as imps,sum(uu) as uu from...
```

Thanks so much for your help.  Brian P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is being caused by the use of the same single quotes within the query which are the same quotes as what you are wrapping the entire query in.

Your options:

1. Escape all the quotes in the query `when freq = \'1\' then \'a\'`
2. Change quotes to be double quotes `when freq = "1" then "a"`
3. Pass the query to bq query command via a file instead. `cat your_query.sql | bq query`

**Option 3**: is the most elegant solution and also helps to organize your code in a nice way keeping SQL as SQL and not having lots of SQL embedded directly in bash code. You wouldn't need to make any changes to the current SQL.

The full example would look like

```
cat your_query.sql | bq query \
  --destination_table abcdefcloud:ds_tables.daily_over_frequency_output \
  --replace \
  --use_legacy_sql=false
```

Where `your_query.sql` would contain:

```
with freq as
(select month as month,campaign_id,campaign,case when  freq = '1' then 'a'
 when freq = '2' then 'b'
 when freq = '3-6' then 'c'
 when freq = '7-9' then 'd'
 when freq = '10-19' then 'e'
 when freq = '20-29' then 'f'
 when freq = '30-39' then 'g'
 when freq = '40-49' then 'h'
 when freq = '50-59' then 'i'
 when freq = '60-69' then 'j'
 when freq = '70-79' then 'k'
 when freq = '80-89' then 'l'
 when freq = '90-99' then 'm'
 when freq = '100+' then 'n'
 else 'other' end as sort,
 freq,sum(imps) as imps,sum(uu) as uu from...
```

Comment: Thanks so much Blakey.  Didn't realize the quotes in the case when could could cause problems.  Love your suggestion about calling the query via file.  Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `freq` column is numeric (it probably should be), then your `CASE` expression should fail, because `3-6` is not a valid number.  Try this version instead:

```
case
    when freq = 1 then 'a'
    when freq = 2 then 'b'
    when freq between 3 and 6 then 'c'
    when freq between 7 and 9 then 'd'
    when freq between 10 and 19 then 'e'
    when freq between 20 and 29 then 'f'
    ...
    when freq > 100 then 'n'
    else 'other' end as sort
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem:

```
freq = '1' then 'a'
```

If you look closely at the quotation marks, you'll notice that they are the same kind used to quote the query :) This ends up being evaluated as something like:

```
freq = then
```

... Which I don't think is what you want. It should "just work", minus any semantic errors in your query, if you use double quotes instead.

Comment: Yes, indeed this was the problem :)  Changing the single to double quotes does fix the problem :)